# Loop out values from a div tag with the xpath and html agility

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape a website. a comparison site and in such exists a div tags class several times so I would loop out information from each div tag to get something like this in my "div" list item:

"phone": 5432432423

"postalcode": 34234

```
            <div class="biz_list">
            <div data-id="39856" class="heart hgraysprite sprite evt_favorite"></div>

            <div class="biz_evals right string_11" style="margin-top: 15px;">

            <span class="star_blanksprite sprite" title="4.5 av 5"><span class="star_wholesprite sprite rate45"></span></span>
            Snittkarakter 4.5<br>av 18 Evalueringer

            </div>
            <div class="biz_info">
                <h3><a href="/profil/39856/r%C3%B8r-service/">Rør Service</a></h3>
                <table class="string_14">
                    <tbody><tr>
                       <td>Postadr.:</td> 
                       <td class="tab_space">Korssund, 6964 Korssund</td> 
                    </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Telefon:</td> 
                <td class="tab_space">577 37 648</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Mobil:</td> 
                <td class="tab_space">992 93 595</td>
            </tr>

                </tbody></table>
             </div>
        </div>
```

my code

```
List<string> div = new List<string>();

        foreach (HtmlNode td in root.SelectNodes("//div[@class='biz_info']"))
        {
            string att = td.InnerText;
            string trimaatt = att.Trim();
            div.Add(trimaatt);
        }
```

Comment: Is this you again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503755/why-can-not-i-run-a-for-loop-in-xpath-html-agility

Comment: no, it's not. Have not seen that post. but would be very happy if wanted to help me

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem?